# I need to share my internet connection every time I turn on the PC

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, internet

I use USB internet connection. It has a dialing software which saves my username and password and auto connects after turning the PC on. I bought a wireless router (TP Link TL-WR720N). I want to use it as a WiFi hotspot to connect my smartphone.

I have plugged one end of an Ethernet cable into the LAN port of the router and another end to the LAN port of my motherboard. Disabled DHCP server and shared internet connection. I get wifi access on my smartphone easily.

But the main problem comes when I shut the PC off and disconnect form power wallet. I need to uncheck the internet share option and recheck the box to get WiFi access on my smartphone. I am tired to re-share my internet connection every time I power up the PC.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include information about your operating system.

Comment: Do you have other enabled network adapters ?

Comment: "_I use USB internet connection_" -- Do you mean you use a 3G usb stick? What you need is a **3G WiFi router** ([example](http://www.tp-link.com/en/products/?categoryid=202)), it would make things a hell of a lot easier, plus it would not require your pc to be on all the time.

Comment: Its a wimax connection from qubee. http://www.greenpacket.com/devices/uh-usb-wimax-modem.html My operation system is windows 7 ultimate.

Comment: @medigeek Make that comment into an answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

"I use USB internet connection" -- Do you mean you use a 3G usb stick?

What you need is a **3G WiFi router** ([example](http://www.tp-link.com/en/products/?categoryid=202)), it would make things a hell of a lot easier, plus it would not require your pc to be on all the time.

Edit: Since you have a WiMax connection, the same company provides wimax indoor modems: http://www.greenpacket.com/devices/dv-wimax-indoor-cpe.html and http://www.greenpacket.com/devices/dx-wimax-indoor-cpe.html

Answer (score 0):

Consider using Wireless Hosted Network as described in
[About Wireless Hosted Network][1]

It is a built in software AP starting from Windows XP, 7, 8 controlled by netsh line commands. There are also numerous GUI´s found in Google also. If you work under Windows, that´s a great fuction to share your upright (you have to dial up before starting) Internet connection. You have to test it out for your special environment of course. The problem of loosing at least this shared Internet connection shutting down your machine on your smartphone remains of course. The smartphone will, I assume, change to your tele service provider, or behaves otherwise, I don´t know.

[1]  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd815243(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I can see another way of doing it, trough IP forwarding, effectively turning your PC into a router.
You can follow this guide (I am going to repeat the steps needed below) : http://www.home-network-help.com/ip-forwarding.html

Open your registry editor (Win+R -> regedit)
Navigate to

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters
```

Turn on IPEnableRouter (set it to 1).
You might also need to turn on your **Routing and Remote Access** service (type Win+R -> **services.msc**, find it and make its startup automatic). Do this only if it doesn't work without it. A reboot may be necessary.

Next, you will have to adjust your router configuration : You will want to have a static LAN IP address for your PC, you can often do this directly on the router, or assign it a fixed address from windows.
Third, adjust your router's DHCP options : adjust the default gateway to fit your PC's IP address.

You should now have network connectivity on any device connected to your router, provided your PC is turned on.

I hope this will work for you, I am not an expert at windows routing, but this procedure usually works with Linux, so there shouldn't be any reason (other than a mistake I have made) for this not to work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried bridging connections, simply by highlighting both Networks and right clicking, Add to bridge?